# jQuery DataTables - FixedColumns - Column Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

So, I've been looking more and more into the DataTables library and am currently exploring all the possibilities with FixedColumns.

https://datatables.net/

https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

I wasn't able to find this example on the site, so I have to ask if it is even possible.  Can one incorporate a pagination that doesn't travel up and down rows, but left and right by columns?  My application for this would be a grade book where you have a set number of students, not more than 20, but the assignments reach into the hundreds, and you just wish to page through those columns showing the grades each student got on those assignments, from Assignment 1 to Assignment 100.

I have seen examples where the visibility of columns can be toggled on and off, so I feel the answer may lie in there somewhere, but it wouldn't be a dynamic feature. For instance, say one grade book full of students has 100 assignments, but another grade book of students only has 50 assignments, one would have to hard code the amount of columns to toggle on and off.

Has some form of side-to-side pagination been developed yet? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do that with jquery datatable.

Moreover you can use [infinite scroll](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_x.html) to make your datatable readable even with 100 assignments.

I hope i answer to your question

Comment: impossible? you mean, just not possible, yet. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, i mean there is nothing implemented in this library to do that yet